# How to convert WebElement to string?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the code i'm trying with .  I'm using C# basic if else statement to compare.

```
IWebElement findtitle = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("heading3"));

if (title = findtitle.Text)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Test Pass");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Test Fail");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigning the value to `title`, not comparing it. Use `==` to compare

```
if (title == findtitle.Text)
```

If you want to compare using ignore case use

```
if (findtitle.Text.IndexOf(title, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)
```

This will check if `findtitle` text contains the text of `title`.